# keep getting null pointer while trying to make a card flip Animation

Tags: android, eclipse, animation

I am trying to make card flip when an item(card) is clicked in the google card list view animation https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

I am working from the example Google cards activity. and i'm trying to make a card flip when I click it like this: http://bit.ly/1aaReU7 
but i keep getting null pointer exceptions.

can you advice me on on the best route to take in order to achieve this?
Here is the the code  that keeps returning null pointer exceptions.  http://goo.gl/SYHQy

and here is the logcat error:

```
07-10 17:02:26.032: D/AndroidRuntime(788): Shutting down VM
07-10 17:02:26.032: W/dalvikvm(788): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.GoogleCardsActivity$GoogleCardsAdapter.flipCard(GoogleCardsActivity.java:154)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.GoogleCardsActivity$GoogleCardsAdapter.access$0(GoogleCardsActivity.java:143)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.GoogleCardsActivity$GoogleCardsAdapter$2.onItemClick(GoogleCardsActivity.java:109)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3533)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-10 17:02:26.187: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
View rootLayout = (View) findViewById(R.layout.activity_googlecards);
```

This will not return a view.  That is why it is crashing.

I'd suggest giving your root view in the activity_googlecards.xml layout an id, and then getting a reference to, like the example below:

```
View rootLayout = (View) findViewById(R.id.root_view);
```

Comment: Thankyou soo much. That was exactly why it was crashing :D :D

Comment: I have a very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/17649285/1463931 can you help me out?