# Keep getting blank views when trying to grab a view from Listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, animation

I am trying to make card flip Animation when an item(card) is clicked in the google card list view animation https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

I am working from the example Google cards activity. and i'm trying to make a card flip when I click it like this: http://bit.ly/1aaReU7 the problem is that the view goes blank right after the card is flipped.
I want the cards back to be the second item on my listview(which is position 1).
accordind to the documentation here:http://bit.ly/1aaReU7 this is how the view for the cards back is supplied:

```
View rootLayout = //your root view;
View cardFace = //your desired card face;
View cardBack = //your desired card back;

FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(cardFace, cardBack);

        if (cardFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            flipAnimation.reverse();
        }
        rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
```

in my case, the card been flipped is the first item and i want the cards back to be the second items view on my listview.
But when i put these  **↓** values in, the card flips(with the card face as the back instead of the specified card-back) and then  disappears leaving a blank view behind.

Here is the values i supplied in for the cards face and  back

```
View rootLayout = listView.getChildAt(position);
View cardFace = listView.getChildAt(position);
View cardBack = listView.getChildAt(1);
```

pls feed me with ideas on how to get the specified view and use it in the flip animation.

for extra detail, here is the full code for the activity.

Activity:  http://pastebin.com/ff1x72yt

xml: http://pastebin.com/MZ5ePjkE

note:the listview is not scrolllable(for testing purposes) and both the first(0) and second item(1) used for this prototype are visible.